# How to access nested html table data?

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

I have tables like :

```
<table id="Maintb">
<tbody>
<tr> 
<td>  <table>   <tr>..</tr>
                 <tr>..</tr>
                 <tr>..</tr>
</table>
<table>     <tr>..</tr>
            <tr>..</tr>
             <tr>..</tr>
</table>
<table>       <tr>..</tr>
            <tr>..</tr>
             <tr>..</tr>
   </table>
</td> 
</tr>
```

The table 1,2,3 contain different number of check-box. If user checked some check- box in this three tables. How can I get checked values. These table are created dynamically.The nested tables do not have id.How it is possible in JavaScript or c#. If some give me some hit.

Comment: It's possible in whatever language you want. But what's the purpose and what do you have already so far?

Comment: jQuery $("#Maintb table")

Comment: jQuery $("#Maintb table3 tr")

Comment: i want to store check-box values that are checked by user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure but as you said you *want to store check-box values that are checked by user*, You can give this a try:

```
var checkedValues = $("#Maintb table input:checkbox:checked").map(function(){
    return this.value;
}).get().join(",");
```

### [**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/p827V/)

**Docs**

- [`map()`](http://api.jquery.com/map/)
- [`:checked`](http://api.jquery.com/checked-selector/)

Hope this will help you!

Comment: If want to put (var checkedvalues) into  c# array how can i do this. Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a JsFiddle to record checked/unchecked http://jsfiddle.net/CJcXp/

`$('.testme').click(function () {
    if (this.checked) {
        console.log($(this).attr('data-val') + ' checked');
    } else {
        console.log($(this).attr('data-val') + ' unchecked');
    }
});`
Hope this helps